# Задать кастомный размер изображений WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Нужно вывести картинку с максимальной шириной 487px
В functions.php пишу вот так

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'licenses', 487 );
}
```

Использую плагин ACF и пытаюсь вывести изображение вот таким образом

```
<?php if( have_rows('licenses_thumbs', 'options') ): ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('licenses_thumbs', 'options') ): the_row();
        $attachment_id = get_sub_field('license_img', 'options');
        $size = "licenses";
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="" />
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Но в атрибуте src пишет (unknow). Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось сделать так

```
<? echo  wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $size ) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы просто wrapper не сделать нужного размера и не вставлять туда картинку из acf?
p.s чтобы картинки вставить как урл в src, в настройках поля в ACF нужно указать Return Format -> URL image

Comment: Вот так $licenses_img = get_sub_field('license_img', 'options');   echo $licenses_img  - отображается. А вот так echo $licenses_img['sizes']['licenses']  - не отображается

Answer (score 0):

в ваших условиях или в циклах нигде не указан с какого поста берется $image[0] , поэтому мне кажется у вас src (unknown), в функции have_rows можно передать еще пост, может так попробуете цыкл переписать? или просто уберите параметр 'options' с функции have_rows()

https://mad-dog.ru/dokumentatsiya-acf-advanced-custom-fields/have_rows/